# How to embed a password protected video by sending password through vimeo GET API 3 c#

Tags: c#, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I'm trying to embed the password protected video's from vimeo, is it possible to get videos by passing passwords with the GET API

Answer (score 1):

Currently password protected videos are only accessible by the owner of that video. Once embedded on a page, a user will be able to enter the password via the player and view the video.

Comment: I need to embed in a mobile app. Is there a way to put in the password from the code instead of the user having to do it? The user has already put a password in to access the app.

Comment: This is not possible for the Vimeo embed code. We recommend you mark the video as "hide from vimeo" and control the password access via your own app, or use the direct video links we offer to users with PRO accounts or greater.

Comment: @Dashron is this still the case ? SO instead of making a video private + pw on VIMEO, we should make the video hidden on Vimeo and control the access to the embeded video on our app directly ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure, I have not worked with any Vimeo tools for some time. I recommend you contact their support for more assistance.